# JAVA Console error

Tags: java, netbeans

*If i run this code below in Netbeans*

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Introduction {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console= System.console();// creates a java Object which has method that allows us to write
        console.printf("Hallo parvel");
    }        
}
```

It gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Introduction.main(Introduction.java:10)
/home/parvel/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds).
```

please help

Comment: `System.console()` isn't supported in most IDEs. It returns `null`.

Comment: To print something: `System.out.println("Hallo parvel");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.io.Console` object is null because there is no console attached to it.

Try to run from command line or attached console to it.

Find more details about it here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111337

Comment: thanx so much, stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

**You need to run this from a terminal using java -jar myjar.jar**

In order to have this print to console using System.console();

You will need to export this as a runnable jar

then you can run java -jar myjar.jar and it will output Hallo parvel

Comment: thanx so much, stay blessed